# WordPress DB search and Replace

Tags: wordpress, replace

In WordPress Is there any work around moving the DB from one server to other without doing Search and Replace. I mean to say assume I am developing a project on local setup and url is protocol//localhost/myproject now after done with build I moved code and DB to production server. So is there any best way other than search and Replace to access the same with different URL.

Comment: export your db and replace http://localhost/myproject  to http://yourliveurl.com after save and import.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL I use; if you use Navicat or SequelPro you can save it so you can run it each time you import data (e.g. when grabbing the latest DB from a staging site to work on it locally):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid,'http://www.oldsite.com','http://www.newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'http://www.oldsite.com','http://www.newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =  REPLACE (meta_value,'http://www.oldsite.com','http://www.newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://www.newsite.com' WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://www.newsite.com' WHERE option_name = 'home';
```

Or you could use https://github.com/veloper/WordPress-Domain-Changer which you need to upload and then delete each time you want to change domain.

Comment: This is similar to search and replace. Instead of using any plugin execute sql code. NOt like that.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer as follow:
Open your site’s wp-config.php and write below code in it

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Before below code

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
```